# Wires through conduit instead of drilling ceiling joists

Tags: dryer, joists, conduit, washer, circuit

I am moving the washer & dryer upstairs in my house and will have a contractor hook-up the 10-3 and 12-2 wires to my main panel, but I am running the wires across my attic.  Instead of drilling 23 joists and pulling both wire through, can I run the wire through 1-1/2 in PVC Schedule 40 conduit. The conduit would be located at the end of the joists where the roof joist attaches then down into a wall below where the washer dryer will be moved to.

Al

Comment: If you run conduit the **whole way** you could skip the cables and run 6 wires (12 Ga hot and neutral, 10 ga 2 hots and a neutral, 10Ga ground which can be shared. Or use EMT rather than PVC and no ground wire is needed (the conduit _is_ the grounding path.) Could be run in 1/2" conduit that way (wires are much  more amenable to conduit fill than cables are.)

Comment: If you use PVC, make sure you use _conduit_, not DWV pipe. Schedule 40 _conduit_ is grey in color water-carrying Schedule 40 is white. I'm not certain what the actual differences are, but your inspector will ding you on it and your contractor should refuse to do the connections after checking out your wiring job if you use the white stuff.

Comment: Flame retardance and UV protection are two of the differences I'm aware of, @FreeMan

Comment: The inside of conduit and fittings is smooth where pipe can have a ridge at least on metallic pipe vs conduit, on top of low smoke uv and will not support combustion. That Ecnerwal mentioned. ++ Is the attic accessible run a protective board along side of the wire and you don’t have to drill or use conduit. See NEC 398.23 I do this quite often down the center with a board on either side, in the corner a single board is fine and has passed inspection for me more times than I can count.